# Getting data from second table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables.

Table1 has columns like

```
ID int
FromAddress int
ToAddress int
```

Table2 has columns like

```
ID int
ZipCode int
```

The Connection between 2 tables is based on FromAddress,ToAdress(from Table1) and ID in table2

Rough data is like in Table1

```
ID     FROMAddress    ToAddress
1      500            620
```

Roughdata is like in Table2

```
ID     ZipCode
500    69999
620    6501
```

I want output like

```
ID     FromZipCode     ToZipCode
1      69999           6501
```

I tried to do Query like

```
Select T1.ID, T2.ZipCode as FromZipCode, T2.ZipCode as ToZipCode
From Table1 T1 join Table2 T2 on T1.FromAddress = T1.ID and T1.ToAddress = T2.ID
```

But this gives me no result.

Comment: JOIN table2 twice.

Comment: @jarlh i couldnt find way :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this, you need to `JOIN` twice:

```
Select T1.ID
    ,T2.ZipCode as FromZipCode
    ,T22.ZipCode as ToZipCode
From Table1 T1
join Table2 T2
    on T1.FromAddress = T2.ID -- first JOIN to get the info for FromAddress
join Table2 T22 
    on T1.ToAddress = T22.ID -- second JOIN to get the info for ToAddress
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join the table twice to get your desired data:

```
SELECT T1.ID,
       T2.ZipCode AS FromZipCode,
       TT2.ZipCode AS ToZipCode --From the second Table2 (TT2)
From Table1 T1 JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.FromAddress = T1.ID 
     JOIN Table2 TT2 ON T1.ToAddress = TT2.ID --Join Table2 for the second time with another alias
```